# Art of Electronics - buck converter ripple current derivation

Tags: power, switch-mode-power-supply, buck

I'm struggling to understand how this buck converter equation in The Art of Electronics can be true.

Page 642 shows this Buck Converter:

[image]

and then these graphs of current and voltage are also provided
[image]

Finally it asks to derive these equations

[image]

I'm struggling with 9.3b, ∆I_in = I_out. Why would the output current be in any way related to the ripple current on the input? It doesn't seem like it should be related at all because the ripple current depends on the component values (like the inductance and capacitances), but the output current only depends on the duty cycle.

You can derive the output current from conservation of energy, with power in = power out. If I do this I get I_out = I_in / D. Clearly the output current only depends on the duty cycle, so why is it related to the input ripple current.

Any pointers on how I can reach the derivation (if the book is really correct) that ∆I_in = I_out would be appreciate. Do I start from conversation of energy? Start from the volt second balance across the inductor maybe?

Comment: So you don't think that the input current is zero when switch is off, and that the input current does not have a ramp up when switch is on and input current is taken to increase the inductor current?

Comment: @Justme I agree with all that, but isn't that the DC component of the input current when the switch is closed? If I understand correctly, the book is talking about the ripple on top of the input current, not the input current. (denoted  ∆I_L in the diagram)

Answer (score 1):

Let's take an example, you have 10V DC input, and need 5V 1A DC output.

Sure, the average input current is 0.5A.

But because the switch is 50% on and 50% off, you will see that input current is either zero or 1A, so ripple of input current matches output DC current.

Comment: I appreciate the help but if I understand correctly it seems like you are saying the output current is equal to the max input current. You can see this isn't true from the graph in the book though. Look at the second to last graph in Figure 9.62, it shows I_out below the max I_in.

Comment: If we assume average output current is 1A, and we assume that ripple current is 0.2A, we need to increase the inductor current from 0.9A to 1.1A when switch passes input current, and when switch is off the inductor current to output must discharge from 1.1A to 0.9A. When switch is on, average input current must be 1A, if average output is 1A. But switch is on for 50% of time, so input takes 1A for 50% of time or no current for 50% of time, so 0.5A on average.

Comment: I think the problem is that they never showed the meaning of \$\Delta I_{in}\$ on any of the graphs; the text just says that it's "the **approximate** peak-to-peak ripple current at the input". I would take this to mean that it's the span from minimum input current (zero) to the average value of the input current while the switch is on.

Comment: @DaveTweed If I'm reading you right (always a question itself) about the minimum input current at zero, then \$I_{_\text{OUT}}=\frac12 \Delta I_{_\text{L}}\$, just as the text on the prior page says it is. (The triangle is obvious so the equation is obvious.) But 9.3b doesn't include the \$\frac12\$ constant. There's another factor of \$2\$, apparently. I've spent no more time than to skim to get here. I may get out some paper, later. But I'll +1 the question, now.